# Binance smart chain wallet open using web3modal

Tags: web3js, blockchain, dapps, binance

Web3modal provides ethereum wallet connect in dapp.
I'd like to connect binance smart chain wallet extentions.
I think it would be possible to edit providerOptions for the each wallet extensions.
Anyone can give me detailed answer for my question?
Thanks

Comment: I am still looking for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following piece of code is an extract of what I use in the dapp I've developed.

```
let providerOptions = {
  "custom-binancechainwallet": {
    display: {
      logo: "../../assets/img/binance-logo.svg",
      name: "Binance Chain Wallet",
      description: "Connect to your Binance Chain Wallet"
    },
    package: true,
    connector: async () => {
      let provider = null;
      if (typeof window.BinanceChain !== 'undefined') {
        provider = window.BinanceChain;
        try {
          await provider.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error("User Rejected");
        }
      } else {
        throw new Error("No Binance Chain Wallet found");
      }
      return provider;
    }
  }
};

let web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
  cacheProvider: true,
  providerOptions,
  disableInjectedProvider: false
});
```